# PDF Generation using iText XFA from template

Tags: itext, xfa

I am trying to generate pdf from template using iText XfaForm. I have to put dynamic table and i am partially successful in displaying dynamic table with data but the if the table has lot of data, it is not adding new page in PDF. only it is displaying the data that can fit into a single page. I created template using Adobe Experience Manager. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src); 

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest)); 
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields(); 
XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa(); 

xfa.fillXfaForm(new FileInputStream(dataFile)); 
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood your question. But can you please add your code to the question? The comments mess up the formatting.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the template. When I use [purchase_order.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/purchase_order.pdf) as template and [data.xml](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/xml/data.xml) as data, I get [purchase_order_filled.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/xfa/cmp_purchase_order_filled.pdf). That result has more than one page using the same code you use. This proves that your code is right, hence the problem must be elsewhere, more specifically in the template.

Comment: If i use individual fields like in Purchase_order.pdf, it is working fine. Thanks for your help. But if i try to put a table with 4 columns and dynamic rows, the table is  not expanding to 2nd page.